# How to Open Window in New Thread and Pass Data?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a Window with a Rich Text Box. How can I open it in a New Thread, then write to the Text Box?

I've tried many different ways with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and using Thread and BackgroundWorker, but I'm not setting it up right. I get errors such as "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." when trying to open the window or write.

I start a hidden background window using Hide(), open with Show():

```
MainWindow mainwindow = this;

myWindow = new NewWindow(mainwindow);
myWindow.Left = this.Left + 605;
myWindow.Top = this.Top + 0;
myWindow.Hide();

myWindow.myRichTextBox.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

I write to it using Actions that are saved to a list, then called at a certain time:

```
List<Action> LogActions = new List<Action>();
Action WriteAction;

// Create Multiple Actions 
WriteAction = () =>
{
    myWindow.myRichTextBox.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Example")) { Foreground = Brushes.White });
};
// Add Actions to List
LogActions.Add(WriteAction);

// Write All Actions in List
foreach (Action Write in LogActions)
{
    Write();
}
```

To simplify, it is basically doing:

```
myWindow.myRichTextBox.AppendText("Example");
```

It is able to pass data without new thread right now. But the mouse freezes for a few seconds when the Rich Text Box is being written to, I thought this might free it up. Would anyone advise against opening in new thread?

Comment: To make it simple, it is very complicated to create controls in a non UI thread. You must communicate with the main thread so that he does the job. For example, you may enqueue actions in a list from secondary thread and dequeue them in main thread (Don't forget to lock the list when enqueuing/dequeuing).

Comment: @Graffito I see, would there be another way to stop the mouse/mainwindow from freezing while the richtextbox is written to? It writes a long list of actions all at once for about 4 seconds.

Comment: In the main thread, a timer may be used to dequeue the actions mentioned in my previous comment..

Comment: @Graffito I will try it out, thanks.

Comment: Creating controls in a non-UI thread is almost always the wrong thing to do. Start by finding out why “the mouse freezes for a few seconds when the Rich Text Box is being written to”. Post code that replicates that.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually best practice for the user interface to stay in the main application thread, where the UI can spawn background threads to perform longer-running tasks. This way, the UI thread can still respond to user input while the background work is underway.

In the case of a Window, `myWindow` with a Rich Text Box that you want to append messages to, `myWindow` would use a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to gather the messages in a separate thread and then update the RTF control through a callback on thread termination (for a `BackgroundWorker` this is the [`OnRunWorkerCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) method).

If the window must run as a separate thread, this helper class will wrap a WPF Window in a new thread and set it up with a new `SynchronizationContext`, however, you will still need thread-safe messaging if you want to communicate between windows in different threads. The [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) collection provides a thread-safe collection that may be useful for this purpose.

```
public static class WindowThreadHelpers
{
    public static void LaunchWindowInNewThread<T>() where T : Window, new()
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint<T>));
    }

    private static void ThreadStartingPoint<T>() where T : Window, new()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
            new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

        var win = new T();
        win.Closing += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames();
            win.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        };

        win.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how you would use it from the main thread

```
WindowThreadHelpers.LaunchWindowInNewThread<NewWindow>();
```